# JQuery ajax - is it possible to return two different sets of data on success?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

Using this ajax request I am returning a view fragment of populated html to insert into a particular div within the layout.

my question is how do I declare #theDiv, I have the id available at the point where the view fragment is constructed (within the view_Controller).

Ideally I would return some json at the same time for instance, specifying:#theDiv, and any other parameters such as which nav bar element should be active etc....

```
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "controller/view_Controller.php",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "html",
      success: function(html){

           $('#theDiv').html(html)

        };
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build an array of information on the backend:

```
$data = array (
    'html' => $html,
    'target' => '#myDiv'
);

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($data);
```

And in your JS:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "controller/view_Controller.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
       $(data.target).html(data.html)
    };
});
```

I don't quite understand what you mean by specifying success and error -- do you mean you want your script to be able to define the Javascript to be called on success?

Comment: great thanks - I didn't realise you could store html within json I remembered reading it was not a desirable circumstance?  as for success etc I meant if another element on page should be changed eg. change the active class on the nav bar, that these things could be passed at the same time

Comment: @davivid There's no reason not to store HTML in JSON as long as it's encoded properly.  For the other point, I would define functions in your original JS as standard named functions.  You could then call them dynamically based on the results of an AJAX call, e.g. `'functions' => array('navbarActive'),` in PHP and `$.each(data.functions, function(){ this(); });` in JS to call the `navbarActive` function.

Comment: nice one, this should really help me with this project

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "controller/view_Controller.php",
          data: dataString,
          cache: false,
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){

               $(data.id).html(data.html)

         };
});
```

Have the script pass back a JSON object with the id attribute set to the id of the element, and have the html element set to the HTML string that you want it set with.